# How add widget count in my app icon?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to add to my android app a notification count on the my apps icon, but i don't know how, i already create my widget, but how can i show it exactly on my app's icon in the screen??

I need to show it when a notification arrive, I already have all the work done!
That's my widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlayout"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" 
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/shapecount"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shapecount"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a notification count on the icon on that sits on the user's home screen, like the little "badges" that iOS has? Or is this for your app icon within one of your Activities (e.g. on the ActionBar)?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to add a notification count on the icon on the user's home screen, like iOS!

Comment: This is not something that Android supports. There are some custom launcher applications that may show badges on certain items, but typically those are things like the number of unread messages or missed calls because that information is available through APIs in the Android SDK.